# How to get a transparent actionbar over viewpager

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to get a transparent actionbar over a viewpager.

I set `windowActionBarOverlay` to true and the background to

```
@android:color/transparent.
```

The top of the viewpager is under the actionBar, but the actionBar is white and not transparent. How can I get the actionBar transparent so the top of the viewpager becomes visible?

I searched everywhere and I can only find answers that say to set windowActionBarOverlay to true and the background tot transparent, but this doesn't seem to work.

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and in onCreate I set a toolbar as actionbar:

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

The activity xml is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_daily" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_daily" app:menu="@menu/activity_daily_drawer" />
```

app_bar_daily xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".DailyActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_daily" />
```

content_daily xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

styles xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ACTION BAR STYLES -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a theme with no action bar
2. Create a layout with a toolbar (with a transaparent background

   ```
    <LinearLayout  
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

       <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:gravity="bottom"
       android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

       <!-- Your view pager -->

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. set the toolbar as your actionbar programmatically (`setActionbar` / `setSupportActionBar`)

Answer (score 0):

In java class, add this function:

```
public void setCustomActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new         ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#60000000")));
        getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_global);

    }
```

And also, you create an Action Bar's layout xml as other normal layout file.